# JSF Report rendering lower thread priority

Tags: java, jsf, seam

I generate huge report with facelts, Excel and PDF,

Using JSF 1.2, Seam 2.2.3

Woundring if i can somehow lower the thread priorty on thease JSF pages since it dosn't realy matter how long the take aslong as the don't disturbe the other parts of the system.

As it is now when i generate 1 file, pdf or excel since it take about 30 seconds or so it slows the rest of the system as well.

Comment: The best advice would be to use a profiler like [VisualVM ](http://visualvm.java.net/) and investigate where the problems are in your report option. Lowering the thread priority will result in affect in lowering a Web App Server thread priority that could be reused to handle other requests as well.

Comment: okey, well would just want that certain page to be less priorities. Will try to use a profiler, but extracting the data for generating the page takes about 6 seconds, while for jsf to render it take 30-40 seconds, and more or less just a table with loads of columns and rows, wich ends upp with about 25 meg of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new thread for creating your reports and set a low priority with [setPriority()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority%28int%29) for it. However I'm unsure of the exact behavior. It will probably lower the priority in regard to other threads. It probably won't have the same effect as setting the priority on the operation system layer.

Comment: How do i get a hold of the JSF Thread? Or start it inside another thread?

Comment: Udo means to do this (or similar) in your action: `Thread t = new Thread(new YourRunnableImplementation()); t.setPriority(<low value>); t.start();`. Still, this isn't a good approach because it will consume server resources and would be harder to maintain.

Comment: You would run the report generation in a thread. However I doubt it would actually help you.